# How do I set Apache.NMS Thread Name

Tags: multithreading, activemq-classic, nms

When I upgraded to Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ 1.5.3, the thread names are now all the same making it impossible to separate out activity.

```
2012-03-15 15:05:09,412 WARN  [ActiveMQ Task]
```

Anyone know how to change this? You cannot change Thread.CurrentThread.Name once it has been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do in this case is to create a new issue using the Jira issue tracker for the Apache NMS client.  You can document the problem and the behavior you are seeking so that the developers can try and make it work in a way that fits your use case.  I don't believe there is currently and way for the thread names to be set externally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by tweaking the task runner factory

```
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Threads.DefaultThreadPools.DefaultTaskRunnerFactory.name = ""
```